# Laptop running hotter on Mint than Windows

Tags: linux-mint, windows, intel, intel-graphics, temperature

I've recently installed (dualboot) Linux Mint 18 on my Sony Vaio [svt15115cxs](https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=SVT15115CXS)
and noticed that it's running louder than on windows, so I checked the temps, and found, that while under load (eg. watching a 1080p/720p youtube vid in firefox on both systems) the CPU runs about 10 °C hotter. (measured with Psensor and `watch -d -n 1 sensors` on linux, and hwinfo64 on windows).
So I've installed TLP and thermald but not much has changed. I've also enabled intel-microcode in the driver manager and installed the latest intel graphics dirver.

What can I do to optimize temps on linux without severely hindering the performance? I really like linux so far, but if it means higher temps then I'll have to stick with windows.

**edit:** Kernel:4.4.0-45 generic

**edit2:** So I just installed manjaro (xfce) and it stays around 72°, which is better than the mint's 77, but it's still way worse than the 52° on win.

Comment: Is this for watching videos on YouTube only or is it a general observation?

Comment: Consider that it may not be the processor.  That it could be the graphics chip.  A few laptops have separate fans so it is easy to tell which is warming up.  Otherwise check if Psensor can "see" the CPU and GPU separately.  Some open-source graphics drivers are not as good as proprietary drivers.  Some graphics companies have distributed proprietary drivers for Linux.  You might check on this as most Linux distributions do not (can not?) distribute / install the proprietary drivers.

Comment: What kernel does it use?  I found, on a different distro, that using a backported kernel did lower the temperature. However, it still seemed higher than on Windows.

Comment: @pfnuesel it's a general observation, I just found watching videos a quick & easy way to compare the two OS.

Comment: @st2000 The notebook only has the integrated intel HD 4000 and psensor doesn't list any GPUs

Comment: @SauceCode I edited the main post with that info

Comment: Try [powertop](https://01.org/powertop) (available as a package on Mint).

Comment: [The notebook only has the integrated intel HD 4000 and psensor doesn't list any GPUs] I find the older the laptop (and the more not-main-stream the graphics (if this is a graphics problem)) the harder it is to solve these heat problems.  I think Mint is based on Ubuntu.  I run my Ubuntu laptop using the Lxde (Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment) desktop for just these reasons.

Comment: @st2000 correct, it's based on ubuntu 16.04. I tried using xfce, which is lighter than cinnamon, but that didn't help. I'm thinking of installing some non-debian based distro, but I doubt that would solve my problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to state which version of Windows you are using and which desktop environment of Linux Mint. If you're using XP, then that is rather lightweight and wouldn't run hot. And if you're running Cinnamon, that might explain the heat if you're on older hardware.

Comment: @DogLover Thanks for your comment. In the previous comment I mentioned that I've tried both xfce and cinnamon and the changes were minuscule. I'm using windows 10. (I didn't think that using xp was a thing, since its support ended 2 years ago and the os itself is 14 years old. Vista and after the gui hw req didn't increase by that much between releases.)

Comment: @Dan Oh, Windows XP is definitely still a thing. It's a testament to its build quality and overall excellence. Businesses were/are rumoured to be paying Microsoft to privately extend support so that they could/can keep running XP. Anyway, that is a weird problem you've got there then since Windows 10 is easily as intensive, if not more, than Cinnamon.

Answer (score 2):

I would try two things:

1. Install powertop and run it with `powertop --auto-tune`. For my laptop I'm using it with crontab: `@reboot /usr/sbin/powertop --auto-tune --quiet 1>/dev/null 2>&1`
2. Use a desktop environment that lets you disable 3D compositing, so you save CPU/GPU power and heat at the cost of a slightly less "modern" desktop :)